# Using Ckfinder with ckeditor with JSP

Tags: java, jsp, ckfinder

I was trying to install ckfinder with ckeditor using java.using php i was succesful,but not with jsp
This is my jsp file.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://ckfinder.com" prefix="ckfinder" %>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>CKEditor CKFinder Integration using PHP</h1>
        <ckfinder:ckfinder basePath="ckfinder/" />
        <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
    </body>
    </html>
```

first of all is this correct?also the `ckfinder basepath`,where should it point to?
When i try this it gives me this errors

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://ckfinder.com cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

pleae help and let me know of more things are required

Answer (score 0):

You need `CKFinder-2.4.jar` file.
For creating taglib give
`<%@ taglib uri="http://cksource.com/ckfinder" prefix="ckfinder"%>`
Finally for adding CKFinder to your CKEditor use
`<ckfinder:setupCKEditor basePath="../ckfinder/" editor="textId" />`

Comment: I hope you got the answer or still you are facing any issues?